# how do you convert current date time in NY time to epoch in python

Tags: python

I need to convert current date time to epoch time in python.

I have tried this, but I am not sure is this tz="New_York/Americas". Is below right?

```
import time

epoch_time = int(time.time())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python's calendar module for this.

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import timegm

current_time = datetime.utcnow()
epoch_time = timegm(current_time.utctimetuple())
```

For more, visit calendar's [timegm](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm).